# R, googleway, matching address by removing word

Tags: r, api, google-maps, geolocation, googleway

If I run the below codes directly, it gives me an error because the address is too specified, however if I remove -272, it works fine.

So how can I keep removing words automatically until the function runs and give me the address,

```
library(googleway)    
 google_geocode(address = "경북 경주시 외동읍 문산공단길 84-272", language = "kr", key = api_key,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API works for me if I use the address in your question. However, using the address in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49569236/5977215) gives me a `ZERO_RESULTS` return.

We can remove the last part(s) of the address after the final space using simple regex in a `gsub()` command.

```
library(googleway)
set_key("your_api_key")

## invalid query
add <- "대한민국 경기도 안산시 단원구 성곡동 강촌로 140"
res <- google_geocode(address = add, language = "kr")
res
# $results
# list()
# 
# $status
# [1] "ZERO_RESULTS"

## remove the last part after the final space and it works
new_add <- gsub(' \\S*$', '', add)

res <- google_geocode(address = new_add, language = "kr")
geocode_coordinates(res)
#        lat      lng
# 1 37.31737 126.7672
```

You can convert this into an iterative loop that will continue to remove everything after the final 'space' character and attempt to geocode on the new address.

```
## the curl_proxy argument is optional / specific for this scenario 
geocode_iterate <- function(address, curl_proxy) {

    continue <- TRUE
    iterator <- 1

    while (continue) {
        print(paste0("attempt ", iterator))
        print(address)
        iterator <- iterator + 1

        res <- google_geocode(address = address, language = "kr", curl_proxy = curl_proxy)
        address <- gsub(' \\S*$', '', address)

        if (res[['status']] == "OK" | length(add) == 0 | grepl(" ", add) == FALSE ){
            continue <- FALSE
        }
    }
    return(res)
}

add <- "대한민국 경기도 안산시 단원구 성곡동 강촌로 140"
res <- geocode_iterate(address = add, curl_proxy = curl_proxy)
# [1] "attempt 1"
# [1] "대한민국 경기도 안산시 단원구 성곡동 강촌로 140"
# [1] "attempt 2"
# [1] "대한민국 경기도 안산시 단원구 성곡동 강촌로"
```

Be careful to make sure the `while` loop CAN actually exit. You don't want to enter an infinite loop.

And remember that even though `ZERO_RESULTS` are returned, the query still counts towards your daily API quota.

Comment: because I am currently using work environment computer, my code is not working without your function "curl_proxy". I just tried to put "curl_proxy" in the geocode_iterate, it doesnt' run. Do you know any solution, combining curl_proxy to geocode_iterate??

Comment: @Arvin I've updated the answer with what I *think* should be the solution. However, I can't test it

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I got an error message not related to curl_proxy but it says "Error: is.character(target_url) is not TRUE " and when I run with debug, debug location is "stopifnot(is.character(target_url))" from function (target_url = "http://www.google.com") code

Comment: AU my address appears like this °­ÃÌ·Î, ´Ü¿ø±¸, ¾È»ê½Ã, °æ±âµµ